# Old Elasticsearch shards are not deleted after relocation

Tags: elasticsearch

Our Elasticsearch cluster has two data directories. We recently restarted all the nodes in the cluster. After the successful restart process, we observed increased disk space usage on few nodes. When we examined the folders inside the data directory, we found that there are orphaned shards.

For example, an orphaned shard "15" exists at location data_dir0/cluster_name/nodes/0/indices/index_name/15, while one of the replicas of the same shard "15" exists on the same node inside other data directory, here at data_dir1/cluster_name/nodes/0/indices/index_name/15. This shard "15" from data_dir1 is also included in cluster metadata and thus, we assume that shard "15" from data_dir0 is an orphaned shard and has to be deleted by Elasticsearch. But Elasticsearch hasn't deleted the orphaned shard yet, even after 6 days since last restart.

We found this topic https://discuss.elastic.co/t/old-shards-on-re-joining-nodes-useful/182661 relating to our issue but it did not help us as in ES did not take care of that orphaned shard. We also raised the question on Elastic forum but we are not getting quick replies. So, I am asking it here as stack overflow has larger community.

Answer (score 2):

This also happened to our cluster, we run elastic 6.1.3. One specific node had 88% of it disk used, it seems there were some shard leftovers from previous relocation on our production index.

To fix this I stopped Elasticsearch on the node (make sure you have plenty of disk-space on your other datanodes), let the relocation of elastic do its work. Once it is done and re-balanced, delete the index folder and start Elasticsearch again, this went quite painless.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Is your cluster green? If so, those shard files should be deleted by Elasticsearch during initialization. But if that shard has unallocated replicas at the time the node rejoined the cluster, Elasticsearch won't remove pre-existing shard files on disk.

You can manually delete the directory if you don't need the shard. Or you can try restarting Elasticsearch on the node and let it delete the files for you.

Answer (score 0):

We also got help from Elastic forum here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/old-shards-not-deleted-upon-relocation/71161/6

Restarting the node did not help and we do not want to manually delete the folders. So, we are going to replace the affected nodes one by one.

@chani It would be great if you can provide any official link to the manual delete suggestion.